# efficiently read in fasta file and calculate nucleotide frequencies in R

Tags: r, fasta

How can I read in a fasta file (~4 Gb) and calculate nucleotide frequencies in a window of 4 bps in length?

it takes too long to read in the fasta file using

```
library(ShortRead)
readFasta('myfile.fa')
```

I have tried to index it using (and there are many of them)

```
library(Rsamtools)
indexFa('myfile.fa')
fa = FaFile('myfile.fa')
```

however I do not know how to access the file in this format

Comment: This might help: http://amunategui.github.io/dealing-with-large-files/ If you are calculating frequencies there is no reason to try to hold the entire thing in RAM at once. There seems to be more than one package which can help you read in data in chunks. E.g. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/chunked/chunked.pdf

Comment: I would recommend `Biostrings`, a bioconductor package. It is very fast and has a series of functions deal with nucleotide freuqency with different length and combinations, such as `Biostrings::oligonucleotideFrequency`.

Comment: I am familiar with that function from `Biostrings` however, I do not know how to read a fasta file into R to actually use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that 'slow' to read in a file that size would be a minute; longer than that and something other than software is the problem. Maybe it's appropriate to ask where your file comes from, your operating system, and whether you have manipulated the files (e.g., trying to open them in a text editor) before processing.

If 'too slow' is because you are running out of memory, then reading in chunks might help. With Rsamtools

```
fa = "my.fasta"
## indexFa(fa) if the index does not already exist
idx = scanFaIndex(fa)
```

create chunks of index, e.g., into n=10 chunks

```
chunks = snow::splitIndices(length(idx), 10)
```

and then process the file

```
res = lapply(chunks, function(chunk, fa, idx) {
    dna = scanFa(fa, idx[chunk])
    ## ...
}, fa, idx)
```

Use `do.call(c, res)` or similar to concatenate the final result, or perhaps use a for loop if you're accumulating a single value. Indexing the fasta file is via a call to the [samtools](http://www.htslib.org/) library; using samtools on the command line is also an option, on non-Windows.

An alternative is to use `Biostrings::fasta.index()` to index the file, then chunk through with that

```
idx = fasta.index(fa, seqtype="DNA")
chunks = snow::splitIndices(nrow(fai), 10)
res = lapply(chunks, function(chunk) {
    dna = readDNAStringSet(idx[chunk, ])
    ## ...
}, idx)
```

If each record consists of a single line of DNA sequence, then reading the records in to R, in (even-numbered) chunks via `readLines()` and processing from there is relatively easy

```
con = file(fa)
open(fa)
chunkSize = 10000000
while (TRUE) {
    lines = readLines(fa, chunkSize)
    if (length(lines) == 0)
        break
    dna = DNAStringSet(lines[c(FALSE, TRUE)])
    ## ...
}
close(fa)
```

Comment: Have been running `scanFaIndex` for over 1 hr now, but command does not finish. is there an alternative solution to have the fasta file read faster?

Comment: Update your question with more details -- output of `sessionInfo()` and the content of  the fasta file (many small sequences or a few large?). I will update my answer with a second approach, but I would have thought it would have been slower...

Answer (score 0):

Load the `Biostrings` Package and then use the `readDNAStringSet()` method

From `example("readDNAStringSet")`, slightly modified:

```
library(Biostrings)
# example("readDNAStringSet") #optional
filepath1 <- system.file("extdata", "someORF.fa", package="Biostrings")
head(fasta.seqlengths(filepath1, seqtype="DNA")) # 
x1 <- readDNAStringSet(filepath1)
head(x1)
```